# showsCameraControls only in landscape UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiimagepickercontroller, cordova-plugins

So I'm trying to force the user to record video in landscape mode with UIImagePickerController.

Thought a good way was to switch the showsCameraControls based on orientation since UIImagePickerController has to run in portrait.

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self showControls];
}

- (void) showControls {
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)) {
        pickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;

    } else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation)) {
        pickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    }
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
[self showControls];
```

This works fine. However when the device is rotated the camera controls are out of place.

Is the only solution here to use AVFoundation instead of UIImagePickerController?

Landscape and controls out of place.

[image: landscape]

Portrait and no controls just like we want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `CDVCamera.m` file and add this 2 methods between `@implementation CDVCameraPicker` and `@end`, it should force the video to be recorded in landscape

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: This results in a distorted recording view however the video file renders correctly once recorded. 

See [recording view screenshot](http://imgur.com/T5bU0wR).

The text line should be horizontal.